# Anyone know the air dates of tokyo ghoul season 3

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Does anyone know the air dates of tokyo ghoul re season 3
I have tried searching it up but no results from the websites I tried

Answer (score 2):

According to [Comicbook/Anime](http://comicbook.com/anime/2018/02/19/tokyo-ghoul-re-anime-premiere-date-april-2018/)

> Tokyo Ghoul is preparing to launch a very important anime comeback. After its ill-met second season, the franchise will release its next series after a lengthy hiatus. So, fans better open up their calendars because Tokyo Ghoul just announced the premiere date of its third season.
>
> According to new reports from Japan, **Tokyo Ghoul:re will begin airing on April 3, 2018.** The anime is set to broadcast on Tokyo MX, the same channel which hosted the anime’s last two installments (via Reddit). **Season three will be taking over the spot which A Place Further Than The Universe occupies on Tuesdays at 11 p.m.**

this is backed up on [AniList](https://anilist.co/anime/100240/TokyoGhoulre)

[image: AniList Tokyo Ghoul:re screenshot]

---

as for English release, currently [Chrunchyroll has a link](http://www.crunchyroll.com/tokyo-ghoul-re/videos) however currently i am seeing

> **Availability Information**
>
> Sorry, due to licensing limitations, videos are unavailable in your region.

which seems not to be just an Australian thing according to [some reviews](http://www.crunchyroll.com/tokyo-ghoul-re/reviews/helpful/page1) having conflicting comments. eg

> Not available in my region?!? Why?!? Why even advertise it with a "watch now" link?
>
> WHY THE FCK THIS IS NOT AVAILABLE IN US?
>
> I think it's unreasonable that some users are rating the series 1 star due to not having it in their region, since it's Crunchyroll's issue, not the series itself.

this is because, according to [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=20173) Crunchyroll only has the rights for Ireland and the United Kingdom

> **Internet Streaming:**
> AnimeLab (Australia and New Zealand)
> Crunchyroll (United Kingdom and Ireland)
> FUNimation Entertainment (Subtitled and Dubbed)
> Hulu (Subtitled)
> Wakanim.tv (Denmark, Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden)

we can assume that FUNimation Entertainment, being one of the main US Localization and Distribution companies for anime, has the rights for US Streaming however they do employ geoblocking for Australian as such i can not verify this

Comment: Thanks that helped but im looking for li ke pacific dates

Comment: @Gamer57 pacific dates? as in airing dates in the pacific region? because japan is one of the bordering countries. if you mean specific dates i gave it, April 3, 2018 and Tuesdays at 11 p.m which means new episodes come out in japan every tuesday

Comment: Us. for me   if u know the dates